# Golang how to unit test private method with receiver

Tags: unit-testing, go, testng

In Go, how to unit test private method with receiver? For example, how to unit test code segment as below.

If initiate an instance of `srv` , then `isShare` is hidden through handle of the instance. So in test code can't call `isShare`.

Have search and read some posts, but they are all about private functions without receiver specified.

```golang
package service

func (s *srv) isShare(id string) ( bool, error) {
    
    record := s.db.Get(id)

    if record != nil {
        return true, nil
    }

    return false, errors.New("record not found.")
}
```

One extra question may be, if having one DB type field instantiated in `srv` instance, then in unit test, how to bind a mock DB field to `srv` instead of the real DB type?

Comment: "So in test code can't call isShare." --- why?

Comment: @zerkms because it is private and not exported.

Comment: To access the unpexorted methods in package `service`, write the tests in the same package.

Comment: @lee so create the tests in the same package?

Comment: You almost _always_ create tests in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

You can call un-exported methods from the same package, so just add your tests to the package. It's very common (basically the norm) for tests files to be in the same package as the code they are testing.